# Comparar el último registro de fecha ingresado con la fecha actual en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario en donde quiero que cada vez que comience un nuevo día, el campo `recaudación` empiece como valor igual a `0`.

Es por eso que he cogido el último registro insertado y lo estoy comparando con la fecha actual, pero no consigo lograrlo, agradecería su ayuda.

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

session_start();

$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("No se ha podido conectar a la Base de Datos");
mysql_select_db("proyectoprueba", $conexion);

$placa = $_POST['placa'];
$recaudacion = $_POST['recaudacion'];
$km = $_POST['km'];
$galones = $_POST['galones'];
$fechahoy = date('Y-m-d');


unset($_POST["placa"]);
unset($_POST["recaudacion"]);
unset($_POST["km"]);
unset($_POST["galones"]);

$query = "SELECT Kilometros FROM registro ORDER BY idregistro desc LIMIT 1";
$resultado = mysql_query($query);

if ($resultado !== false) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) !== 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $kmAnt = $row['Kilometros'];
        if ($km >= $kmAnt) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO registro VALUES(NULL, 'ADF-189', '$fechahoy', now(), '$recaudacion', '$kmAnt','$km','$galones')";
            $resultado = mysql_query($query);
            mysql_close($conexion);
        } else {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>aviso();</script>";
            $variable = "<script language='javascript'> alert('El kilómetro insertado es menor que el anterior. Ingrese otro valor.');</script>";
            $_SESSION["aviso"] = $variable;
            mysql_close($conexion);
        }
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO registro VALUES(NULL, 'ADF-189', '$fechahoy', now(), '0', '0','$km','0')";
        $resultado = mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close($conexion);
    }
} else {
    mysql_close($conexion);
}

$consultarfecha = "SELECT fecha FROM registro ORDER BY idregistro desc LIMIT 1";
$resultadofecha = mysql_query($consultarfecha);
$resultadofecha = strtotime($resultadofecha);

if ($fecharesultado !== $fechahoy) {

    $consultarfecha = "INSERT INTO registro VALUES(NULL, 'ADF-189', '$fechahoy', now(), '0', '$kmAnt','$km','$galones')";
    $resultadofecha = mysql_query($consultarfecha);
    mysql_close($conexion);
} else {
    $consultarfecha = "INSERT INTO registro VALUES(NULL, 'ADF-189', '$fechahoy', now(), '$recaudacion', '$kmAnt','$km','$galones')";
    $resultadofecha = mysql_query($consultarfecha);
    mysql_close($conexion);
}

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas un 'echo' de las variables $fecharesultado y $fechahoy antes del if y después pongas un 'die;'. Esto hará que se pare la ejecución y puedas ver que datos estas obteniendo. Al parecer no son del mismo tipo.

Comment: Estás cambiando dos veces el valor de `$resultadofecha`: `$resultadofecha = mysql_query($consultarfecha)` y `$resultadofecha = strtotime($resultadofecha)`.